# Websocket spring boot app deployed on EKS by using ALB Ingress controller doesn't work

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes-ingress, amazon-eks, spring-websocket, aws-application-load-balancer

I'm trying to deploy Spring boot websocket application to AWS EKS with ALB ingress controller. The application works fine when deployed on aws elastic beanstalk with aws classic load balancer. On AWS EKS cluster, the deployed pod is up and running, but it can't connect to the websocket - health checks are failing with timeout. I'm sending ingress, service and deployment yaml files. Does anyone know if I'm missing something from the setup?

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: xxxxx-dev-ws-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: alb
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internet-facing
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/target-group-attributes: stickiness.enabled=true,stickiness.lb_cookie.duration_seconds=60
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/load-balancer-attributes: idle_timeout.timeout_seconds=600
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/listen-ports: '[{"HTTPS":443}]'
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: TCP
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/certificate-arn: arn:aws:acm:us-east-1:xxxxxxxxxx:certificate/110a2314-db4e-46ed-bbfa-c09345754794
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/target-type: ip
spec:
  rules:
    - host: dev-ws.xxx.com
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /ws-chat/*
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: wschatapi
                port:
                  number: 80

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: wschatapi
spec:
  selector:
    app: wschatapi
  ports:
    - port: 80
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 5000
      nodePort: 31012
  type: NodePort

apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: ws-chatapi
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: ws-chatapi
      environment: dev
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: ws-chatapi
        environment: dev
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: ws-chatapi
          image: xxxxxxx.dkr.ecr.xxxx.amazonaws.com/ws-chatapi
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          ports:
            - containerPort: 5000
```